# You have purple prose, and you have basic writing- What's the median called?

Tags: creative-writing, style

To start with, you have a form of description and furtherance of the intended narrative composed almost wholly of a horribly verbose and impenetrably confusing style known disaffectionately as "Purple Prose" (Somewhat reminiscent of literature translated from the  French)

Then you have writing that says what needs to be said.

What is the middle ground, where the writing is interesting and engaging, but not egregiously so like **Dwarf Fortress** used to be? And is there a name for this, besides "Good style"? I've never noticed anyone call this anything but "Good style" before, and their definitions were somewhat scattered.

Another thing, I don't mean this question to be answered in a subjective manner- I am interested in the facts, like a commonly accepted name for this writing style. This middle part doesn't have to be "Good" either, it just has to exhibit symptoms of both sides without being too far on either extreme.

Comment: As an aside, the opposite of purple prose is also known as "[beige prose](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeigeProse)" (obligatory TV Tropes warning).

Comment: No problem, I love TV Tropes

Comment: So do I. It's just kind of a running gag on the network to leave a warning whenever you link to TV Tropes, because it's a *massive* time sink; someone clicking the link without knowing what they're in for can get stuck there for hours. Heck, I've been using it for years and I *still* get stuck there for hours. But I digress.